# Optimization in handling kmalloc return

Tags: linux, gcc, optimization, linux-kernel

So I was wondering why while checking the return value of a kmalloc, we don't use "likely" hints like so:

`void *ptr = kmalloc(size, GFP_KERNEL)
 if (unlikely(!ptr)) 
    return err;`

My assumption is, of course, that kmalloc does not fail very often. I have a hard time remembering the last time that it failed. Based on this, would it not be a useful recommendation to the compiler?

Comment: ...if you go even further, then the above code is not fully correct (consider potentiality of `size == 0`). The right check should be `ZERO_OR_NULL_PTR(ptr)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably can't hurt to do this, but unless you are running your mallocs in a tight loop, it probably will have a negligible impact on your runtime, compared to the cost of the malloc itself.

Answer (score 1):

First a side note that kmalloc is just a macro which can expand to different function calls depending on args. The funcs it expands to are annotated with `__attribute__((__malloc__))`, which allows the compiler to assume malloc-like behaviour. I don't know what optimisations are enabled by this practice, but an expectation that the function does not fail is most likely taken advantage of.